# jQuery Trigger Call in CarouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, caroufredsel

I have a CarouFredSel instance that has DIVs in the main carousel and images in the pager carousel.

In the $pager.find().click(function{}), If I click on one of the thmumbnails in the pager, it should scroll to the correct image in the main carousel, but does not.

I have narrowed it down to the following block:

```
$pager.find( 'img' ).click(function() {
     var src = $(this).attr( 'src' );
     $carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]' ] );
});
```

The line:

```
$carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]' ] );
```

is what is attempting to link the **IMAGE** that I clicked on and send the carousel to the proper **DIV**.  I need to change this somehow so that the click function looks for the **DIV** containing this **IMAGE**.  Any suggestions? Or would it just be easier to label the divs and images and call from there?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  What I did was in the *#carousel*, each **DIV**, I set an **ID**. In the *#pager*, I set an **ALT** that corresponds with it's matching **DIV ID**.

I replaced:

```
var src = $(this).attr( 'src' );
$carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'img[src="'+ src +'"]' ] );
```

with:

```
var src = $(this).attr( 'alt' );
$carousel.trigger( 'slideTo', [ 'div[id="'+ src +'"]' ] );
```

I've run through the loop several times without error.